# List<String[]> only return last row in table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i want to save record data to a string array and save string arrays to a list

my code:

```
public List<String[]> getAllRecords(String table){
        try {
            List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
            openDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query,null);
            int count = cursor.getColumnCount();
            String[] record = new String[count];
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        record[i] = cursor.getString(i);
                    }
                    list.add(record);
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            //log for test list content
            int a = list.size();
            for (int i=0;i<a;i++){
                String[] s = list.get(i);
                for (int j = 0;j<s.length; j++){
                    Log.i(TAG, "getAllRecords: "+s[j]);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }catch (Exception e) {return null;}
    }
```

but just last record added to list for 10 time !

```
07-19 17:13:23.369 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: 12
07-19 17:13:23.369 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: name9
07-19 17:13:23.369 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.369 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.369 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.369 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: biography9
07-19 17:13:23.369 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.369 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: 12
07-19 17:13:23.369 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: name9
07-19 17:13:23.369 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.369 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.369 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.369 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: biography9
07-19 17:13:23.369 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: 12
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: name9
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: biography9
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: 12
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: name9
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: biography9
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: 12
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: name9
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: biography9
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: 12
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: name9
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: biography9
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: 12
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: name9
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: biography9
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: 12
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: name9
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: biography9
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: 12
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: name9
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: biography9
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: 12
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: name9
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: biography9
07-19 17:13:23.373 10170-10170/com.package.app I/Tag:Database: getAllRecords: null
```

how i can resolve this problem or how can get all records and save to list ?

Comment: move `record = new String[count];` inside `do`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh thank you,problem solved.I'm some wacky :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the `record` array inside the loop over the records in the query results:

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do {
        String[] record = new String[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            record[i] = cursor.getString(i);
        }
        list.add(record);
    }while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Without that, you use a single `record` array,
and for each row you overwrite its content,
and re-add to `list`.

Answer (score 0):

move your `list.add(record);` in to your looping. code like this.

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            record[i] = cursor.getString(i);
            list.add(record);
        }
    }while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

I hope can resolve your problem.